# Getting output from shell command in json format

Tags: jq

I have a command on printers status, that i want to get in json format
here is a command and output:

```
qchk -AW  

Queue                Dev            Status       Job Files              User         PP   %  Blks  Cp Rnk
-------------------- -------------- --------- ------ ------------------ ---------- ---- --- ----- --- ---
PRTS0910  hp@PRTS0910    DOWN     
                         QUEUED     10872 test.ksh           root                    1   1   1
                         QUEUED     10873 test.ksh           root                    1   1   2
PRTS09102 hp@PRTS09102   READY    
PRTS0913  hp@PRTS0913    READY    
PRTC1401  hp@PRTC1401    READY    
PRTS1018  hp@PRTS1018    READY    
PRTS0TESTQ PRTS0TEST      DOWN     
                         QUEUED     10871 print.ksh          root                    1   1   1
```

I have got a script on  kshell with jq using:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
qchk -AW | tr -s ' ' |  jq -sR   'split("\n") |
      .[2:-1] |
        map(split(" ")) |
      map({"Printer": .[0],
           "device": .[1],
           "state": .[2],
           "job": .[3],
           "something": .[4],
           "somth2": .[5]})'
```

The problem is, that i think, I do not understand jq working principles, and can not understand how jq could process delails( jobs)  rows - under printer rows, so this script gives me all json like structure in one row like :

```
{
    "Printer": "PRTS0910",
    "device": "hp@PRTS0910",
    "state": "DOWN",
    "job": "",
    "something": null,
    "somth2": null
  },
  {
    "Printer": "",
    "device": "QUEUED",
    "state": "10872",
    "job": "test.ksh",
    "something": "root",
    "somth2": "1"
  },
  {
    "Printer": "",
    "device": "QUEUED",
    "state": "10873",
    "job": "test.ksh",
    "something": "root",
    "somth2": "1"
  },
  {
    "Printer": "PRTS09102",
    "device": "hp@PRTS09102",
    "state": "READY",
    "job": "",
    "something": null,
    "somth2": null
  },
```

but i need add somwhere in my code lines to filter job lines under printers with something like this (to process lines -"QUEUED     10871 print.ksh          root                    1   1   1") :

```
map(split(" ")) |
      map({"Staus": .[0],
           "Job number": .[1],
           "file": .[2],
           "user": .[3],
           "something3": .[4],
           "somth4": .[5]})'
```

to get master detail json object

Any help

Here is a sample output from qchk, sorry am not very expierenced in SO editing:

```
# qchk -AW
```

Queue                Dev            Status       Job Files              User         PP   %  Blks  Cp Rnk

```
PRTS0408             hp@PRTS0408    READY    
PRTS0416             hp@PRTS0416    READY    
PRTS0417             hp@PRTS0417    READY    
PRTS0702             hp@PRTS0702    RUNNING   110816 /alliance/PRINT/PR root          0 100   140   1   1
                                    QUEUED    110848 /alliance/PRINT/PR root                  141   1   2
                                    QUEUED    110849 /alliance/PRINT/PR root                  141   1   3
                                    QUEUED    110850 /alliance/PRINT/PR root                  141   1   4
                                    QUEUED    110856 /alliance/PRINT/PR root                  141   1   5
                                    QUEUED    110857 /alliance/PRINT/PR root                  141   1   6
                                    QUEUED    110858 /alliance/PRINT/PR root                  141   1   7
                                    QUEUED    110859 /alliance/PRINT/PR root                  141   1   8
                                    QUEUED    110860 /alliance/PRINT/PR root                  141   1   9
                                    QUEUED    110861 /alliance/PRINT/PR root                  140   1  10
                                    QUEUED    110862 /alliance/PRINT/PR root                  140   1  11
                                    QUEUED    110884 /alliance/PRINT/PR root                  141   1  12
                                    QUEUED    110885 /alliance/PRINT/PR root                  141   1  13
                                    QUEUED    110886 /alliance/PRINT/PR root                  141   1  14
PRTS0714             hp@PRTS0714    RUNNING   110984 /alliance/PRINT/PR root          0 100    11   1   1
PRTS0723             hp@PRTS0723    READY    
PRTS0901             hp@PRTS0901    READY    
PRTS0906             hp@PRTS0906    READY    
PRTS0907             hp@PRTS0907    READY    
PRTS0909             hp@PRTS0909    READY    
PRTS0910             hp@PRTS0910    READY    
PRTS09102            hp@PRTS09102   RUNNING   111017 /alliance/PRINT/PR root          0 100   141   1   1
                                    QUEUED    111018 /alliance/PRINT/PR root                  140   1   2
                                    QUEUED    111019 /alliance/PRINT/PR root                  140   1   3
```

In two words row is the printers, and they are owners of their print jobs, and I need to somehow get this relation in json.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please follow the [mcve] guidelines more closely.  In the present case, it would be helpful to see an informative sample of the output you're expecting.

Comment: I did not have `qchk` command to test, if you could, please provide a sample as input (= output of `qchk` command ) to test on.

Comment: I don't think jq is the right tool to use here